# Advancements in Anti-Virus technology

Tags: anti-virus

Is there any site where I can find articles on current advancements in the Anti-Virus technology?

Answer (score 3):

Try the virus DB of major AV vendors:

- http://vil.nai.com/
- http://www.f-secure.com/en_EMEA/security/security-lab/latest-threats/virus-descriptions/
- http://www.sophos.com/security/analyses/viruses-and-spyware/
- http://www.viruslist.com/en/weblog
- http://www.avast.com/eng/viruses.html

Comment: These articles discusses about virus threats not technology as a whole. I've found a way. I think YouTube has many videos that shows what's hot in security technology.